# What should I do when answers contradict each other, but both sides seem correct?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I recently asked [a question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42427/is-there-a-legal-way-for-us-presidents-to-extend-their-terms-beyond-two-terms-of) on the [*Politics* Stack Exchange site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour), which I thought was a "Yes or No only" question and the first three answers where clearly stating no. I was about to accept an answer, but then the first yes answer popped in, then another one. Both, Yes an No answers, support their claims with evidence. However, I'm sure only one side can be right.

I'm not sure which answer I should accept and how to proceed. Politics is not my area of expertise and unlike on Stack Overflow, I can hardly judge by myself what is correct. My usual approach would be to just accept the most upvoted answer, but I feel that would not be the best way this time.

How do I decide which answer should be the accepted one? Should I just wait two weeks and check the votes? What is the Stack Exchange way of handling this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I'm not sure which answer I should accept and how to proceed.

Then **don't accept an answer**. It's mentioned a few times in the [Help](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) [Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> ## What should I do when someone answers my question?
>
> ...
>
> - As the asker, you have a special privilege: you **may** accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
>
> ...
>
> Accepting an answer is **not mandatory**; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

> ## What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?
>
> When a user receives a good answer to their question, that user has the **option** to "accept" an answer.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

In the end, acceptance of one answer or another is just a nice 'bonus' you can give as an author of the question. What matters far more is the opinion of the entire community, who will 'choose' one answer by giving it the most upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting an answer is not about whether it is “right” or “wrong”.

As per its tooltip, it should be the answer that helps you the most that you accept, to reward the effort that answerer volunteered to help you.