# Are we aiming for a single answer that covers everything about a question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

So I was thinking about why only one answer can be accepted to any particular question on Stack Exchange. I was thinking, most likely, so there would develop one answer that covers "everything" about a question which would become "accepted."

But this implies repeating a lot of information from existing answers, which can be annoying to users seeking answers to such questions and can generate a lot of downvotes if it's very redundant for the sake of "completion!" Plus there's the matter of, if the asker wanted to change the "accepted" answer to one recently "overtaking" the existing one, the consequent loss of 15 reputation to that answerer, which I really don't like the idea of doing this to in this case.

So should I, in fact, be "redundant" to form a singular, coherent, complete answer to a question despite the information being present in other answers already? I do have a preference to only add what I know in addition to what's there, if with a little basic background with the other answers, to questions with existing "decent" or better answers. This does make me prefer that either multiple answers could be "accepted" or there was some other system of the asker saying "nice answer" to more than one answer, without having to choose only one of answers that ultimately cover it which themselves are incomplete!

Though if Stack Exchange really prefers to consolidate ALL essential information into one answer, I can cover the basics on everything and then add my own information in my answers.

Comment: Accepted for the original poster means *this answer helped me most*. That doesn't need to be the most complete answer or, heck, even the correct answer. The best answer is indicated by votes from the community. Whether that is a complete or a to the point answer highly depends on the question/tag, the specific site and the voting habits of visitors and voters.

Comment: Your repetition logic doesn't make sense. One should simply link to the other answer, along with adding their own content for the sake of completion.

Comment: I am talking about other answers to the same question, which are readily viewable right there. For many answers to repeat the same information can be annoying to many users, and likely generate downvotes. Links would be redundant if they are to answers on the same page!

Comment: As [rene explained in the first comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331158/are-we-aiming-for-a-single-answer-that-covers-everything-about-a-question-on-sta#comment1080101_331158) the asker may (or may not) choose *only one* answer. Everyone is free to vote or award bounties to any answers. They may also leave a brief comment explaining why an answer was most helpful or point out any shortcomings - all of which others may adopt as their own beliefs or reject outright.  Each *new* answer should be more than an incremental improvement of a prior one and requires essential added info

Comment: I think people are missing the OP's main point.  The question "_Why was Lincoln a great president?_" might have many answers each giving one or two points.  Each of those answers is "correct", and one of them might be "accepted" for the questioner's purpose.  But there really isn't a "best" answer.  Wouldn't it be the right thing to do if he added one more answer that **consolidates all those points into one list**?  (The points could be quoted or reworded, but with credit given to each individual original answerer.  There doesn't even need to be any original content (like a Masters thesis).)

Comment: @RayButterworth Do you have another [example](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that is on-topic for one of our sites? What purpose would there be to have 1001 answers, with the first 1000 answers listing one point and the 1001st answer linking to the first 1000 answers; followed shortly thereafter by yet another answer. --- If there is no "*best*" answer for months, or years, then the asker may choose to not accept an answer ***or*** they can accept one that is clearly incorrect. Be clearer about what improvement your change will bring. Offer better answers, don't copy.

Comment: @RayButterworth: "*The question "Why was Lincoln a great president?" might have many answers each giving one or two points.*" And that's precisely why such a question is generally considered "Too Broad" for our system to handle.

Comment: @Rob, perhaps a better example is when someone answers with "_There are some good answers here, but they are all missing the additional fact that …_". This is the best answer, but by itself it is almost useless. It is incomplete because it only refers to the other parts rather than explicitly saying them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it bad form to include information from other answers in your own answer (with references)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64329/is-it-bad-form-to-include-information-from-other-answers-in-your-own-answer-wit) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4551/282094

Comment: I'm **surprised by all these down votes** as I would like to accept multiple answers once in a while. Look at one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303052/concatenating-strings-rows-using-dplyr-group-by-with-mutate-or-summarize/69513200#69513200), which **has three answers to overcome the problem. Which one is the best?**  I ran a [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69513200/3607712) to endorse an accepted answer. But, the processing time differs only by seconds for a reasonably large data set and a different answers might work better in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example [IPS.SE](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3272/7238) where there isn't necessary one answer, or a *correct* one: [Is this site, essentially, a centre for primarily opinion-based questions?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1421/7238)

[How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/7238), you need [a good question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [What should I do when answers contradict each other, but both sides seem correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330136/282094) explains choosing an answer.

[How do we know if an answer is correct?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3626/7238) - [Broad Questions, Definitive Answers, and the Limits of Personal Experience as Evidence](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3580/7238) and [What is Enough to Back It Up?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3024/7238) all deal with how to make your personalized answer shine above the others.

If you want to be a chosen answer and get the most upvotes it won't come from repeating what is already known, it will come from providing something better; unless your answer is just 'good enough' and quick, as that is sometimes the *winner*.

Answer (score 2):

Answers should be complete on their own, and if having multiple complete answers requires "repeating a lot of information", that suggests that the *question* is the problem. If a given piece of code has a problem, two people can suggest two different approaches to mitigate it. The only repeated information is the diagnosis of the problem; the solutions should take up the majority of the answer.

The only way there would need to be "lots" of repetition is if the problems in the question are so numerous or a singular problem is so substantial that explaining the problem requires a massive effort. Both cases are knocking on "too broad" territory.

Comment: Yes, I do tend to ask broad questions, and I'm working on it. Though on something as technical as Stack Overflow I may do better. The other thing is when questions get "opinionated," which mine might be, this tends to attract downvotes. It can be tricky on more subjective matters such as interpersonal skills, and there does seem to be some dissonance between SE objective QA standards and the inherent subjectivity of some of its topics.